# Extraer elementos de Array sin índices PHP

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

En Laravel realizo una consulta en el *controlador*, buscar por fecha y otros parámetros. Luego, en la `view` imprimo los datos de la consulta con un ciclo `foreach` para mostrarlo en la vista. Pero, necesito acceder al primer elemento de una columna llamada `kilometraje`. Entonces, realizo lo siguiente:

```php
<?php $min=array($com->kilometraje);?>
```

Pero el valor devuelto es este:

```php
array(1)[{[0]=>int(10)}array(1)[{[0]=>int(12)}array(1)[{[0]=>int(14)}array(1)[{[0]=>int(16)}
```

Comment: No es necesario repetir las preguntas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/324428/extraer-primer-elemento-de-array-php

Comment: La pregunta repetida [Extraer primer elemento de array php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/324428/extraer-primer-elemento-de-array-php) ya no existe.

Comment: El array sí tiene índices, aunque son numéricos y puedes acceder a ellos en la misma forma que lo haces con array asociativo: `foreach($array as $key => $value)` donde puedes omitir `$key =>` para iterar solo sobre los valores.

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta!, siguiendola hice lo siguiente por favor corrigeme si tengo un error <?php $min=array($com->kilometraje);?>
<?php foreach($min as $key=>$value)


  echo var_dump($min[$value])
;?> pero me da el siguiente error Undefined offset:10, justo en el primer valor el que quiero obtener me podrias explicar que estoy haciendo mal? muchas gracias

Comment: `$min[$value]` no está definido porque estás tratando de usar el valor como clave. Usa simplemente `$value`, que es el valor o, si aún quieres hacer referencia al array `$min[$key]`

Comment: Listo muchas gracias por la información, saludos, no se si puedo calificarte porque no veo un enlace para ponerte positivo, gracias